# Finding a specific file on a site using jsoup

Tags: java, hyperlink, zip, jsoup

So i'm trying to create a little program that updates a World of Warcraft addon for me. Im using jsoup to get a list of links on a specific site. How do I ignore files/links that don't end in .zip?

This is my link list so far, as you can see it will print a list of all the links on the site. The goal is to only find .zip files (there are only two). And then download one of them. Direct link to download changes every time they update the addon, so I can't just download a specific link. I need to find the latest version every time.

```
public static void LinkList() {
    Document doc;
    try {


        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.tukui.org/dl.php").get();


        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {


            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[attr$=value]` selector to checks if `attribute` ends with `value`

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href$=zip]");
```

Demo:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.tukui.org/dl.php").get();
Elements links = doc.select("a[href$=zip]");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element link : links) {
    System.out.println("link : " + link.attr("href"));
    list.add(link.attr("href"));
}

String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

System.out.println("array content:" + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
link : http://www.tukui.org/downloads/tukui-15.79.zip
link : http://www.tukui.org/downloads/elvui-6.82.zip
link : /client/win/tc2430.zip
array content:[http://www.tukui.org/downloads/tukui-15.79.zip, http://www.tukui.org/downloads/elvui-6.82.zip, /client/win/tc2430.zip]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to save the list in to an array?

Comment: @user2599508 What do you mean? What type of array you want it to save it? `Element[]`, `String[]`, other?

Comment: String. The one I want will probably be at the same place in the array every time i want to use it, that means I can use the array later to actually download the file I want, which is http://www.tukui.org/downloads/elvui-6.82.zip.

Comment: @user2599508 I updated my answer with code that will put output in array of Strings, but I wouldn't probably return array but just `List<String>` because it will have same values and you can use it in same way as arrays.